# How-to change apple ID email address correctly

Tags: apple-id

I have old email address address1@domain.com as an apple id. How to change email address to address2@domain.com correctly? I have only 1 iOS device. Should i log out from all services and change it through appleid page or i can change it directly from iOS devise without logging out from services (iMessage, iTunes etc.)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you first sign out of any service or device that uses your Apple ID, except for your primary iOS device, if you want to use it to change your email. From there, you can change your Apple ID email address from the iCloud preferences.

Check out this article for information on how to change your Apple ID: [Change your Apple ID](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202667)

Comment: Did you read the article you linked?  It’s correct. Your first paragraph offers different (incorrect) advice than the article.

Comment: Thank you. I updated my answer to better reflect the article.